# Html.ActionLink to up located controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

In the current controller **Views/Users** I have

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.UserId }), style: "column-action"),
```

I have another view like **Views/Comissions**

So I want to add at the grid `Html.ActionLink` to up located controller

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Comission", "Index", "Comission", new { id = item.UserId }), style: "column-action")
```

But I see wrong URL  like

```
http://localhost:51381/Users?Length=16
```

instead of it should be like

```
http://localhost:51381/Comission/Index/123-sfsdf-2342342-ssdfsdf
```

Any clue how to fix it?

Comment: Basically, you are using the wrong overload of Html.ActionLink: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686260/asp-net-mvc-adding-querystring-length-to-actionlinks

Comment: @QuetiMporta Cool  ! Put it like an answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the method you are creating the link is using the incorrect overload of the Html.ActionLink.

You will need to add `null`

Take a look at this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686260/asp-net-mvc-adding-querystring-length-to-actionlinks) to see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `null` as last argument (which stands for `htmlArguments`) to use the correct `Html.ActionLink` overload:

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Comission", "Index", "Comission", new { id = item.UserId }, /*here ->*/null), style: "column-action")
```