# MVC 5 Link issue with sub 'Length=10' showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi im quite new to MVC 5 but not .net c#

im having a issue with `@Html.ActionLink`

the links keep adding 'Length=10' on the end

this is my link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reporting", "Reporting", "MenuRouter", new { @class = "Reporting" }, new { hidefocus = "hidefocus" })
```

Iv tried moving things about and I still get the 'Length=10' on the end

any help Thanks Tim

Comment: Have you searched this on SO? It has been answered many times [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/824279/1199711), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2686260/1199711), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4357856/1199711)...

Comment: @Zabavsky yes I did still had many problems, its on here to many time with so many solutions and couldn't figure out one that was going to help me :( i have fixed it now

Comment: @Zabavsky plus some that I have looked at are for MVC 3 and 4 but im sorry I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the reason is because; the MVC pipeline is trying to serialize a string object, via the `actionlink` method

The method calls this:

```
public static string ActionLink (this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
```

Your best bet is to try and using a `new {}` on the controller try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reporting", "Reporting", new { Controller = "MenuRouter"}, new { @ID = "Repoting" ,  hidefocus = "hidefocus" })
```

This will certainly remove the `Length=10` this is happening because there is no routes stated with a length, the property value and name will be appended and the query string parameter.

The above should fix your issue. Alan

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reporting", "Reporting", "MenuRouter", null, new { @class = "Reporting", hidefocus = "hidefocus" })
```

Comment: thanks Saranga I tried this way and it's still the same issue.

Comment: @TimDime: Really? It's strange. I'm using this in my applications.